# Ошибка Json при обращении к vk: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, vkontakte-api

Код:

```
import requests
result = requests.get('https://vk.com/dev/users.get',params={'user_ids':1})
print(result.json())
```

Вывод:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы выполняете запрос не в API, а на страницу документации.

Запрос в API выглядит примерно так:

> https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52

Ответ:

```
{
  "response": [
    {
      "id": 210700286,
      "first_name": "Lindsey",
      "last_name": "Stirling"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!